# d3 drawing is too big for containing div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I draw a chart using d3, I create a div called `node`. I append this `node` to the body, set the `node` as a property on the controller that draws the chart inside the `node`). In my function that resizes the width I use to draw the chart, I say, `this.width = this.node.width()`, and when I draw the chart, I have:

```
vis = d3.select(this.node)
    .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', self.width)
```

Why does the d3 drawing appear to be bigger than the div that contains the chart? In this screenshot, you can see the chart appears cut off on the right.
[image: cut-off chart]

When I stretch the screen to the right, I can see more of the graph, but no matter how far I stretch it, I can't see all of the graph.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is going to be difficult to debug without an example of the code you are using. Is it possible to put up a jsfiddle so we can have a look at what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The width that you set for the SVG doesn't really matter that much. Like the `div` it is only the container for the content. You have to make sure that the content fits as well. In your case, you need to set the output range of the scale you're using for the x axis to be within the width of your container. Depending on any labels/legends you may have, you might need to set it to be less than the entire width.

Comment: I want the range of data I'm plotting to be the same. That is, I don't want to draw fewer bars when the window shrinks, I just want the chart to become skinnier.

Comment: If you set the width of the bars based on the scale you use for the x axis, this will happen automatically when you change the output range.